# React Native Side Menu (Navigator) does not cover entire screen

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

I have this code for my Side Menu's homescreen:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableHighlight, Image } from 'react-native';
import { DrawerActions } from 'react-navigation';

export default class HomeScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    drawerLabel: 'Home'
  }
  render(){
    return  (
      <View style={styles.view}>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())}
        style={styles.touchableHighlight} underlayColor={'rgba(0,0,0,0.8)'}>
          <Text style={styles.open}> OPEN </Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <Text style={styles.text}> This is the homescreen </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    view: {
      flex: 1,
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      backgroundColor: 'white'
    },
    text: {
      fontSize: 26,
      color: 'purple'
    },
    touchableHighlight: {
      width: 50,
      height: 50,
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      borderRadius: 50,
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      position: 'absolute',
      left: 10,
      top: 10
    },
    open: {
      color: 'white',
      fontSize: 16,
      fontWeight: 'bold'
    }
})
```

I've tried many things, mainly simple stuff like adjusting width and height but nothing seems to be working. I'm not that great of a coder but I'm almost sure it could be with the fact that my Drawer Navigator is being exported as a component for a **main** Homeview.

If you scroll down I've shared a code snippet from my main Homeview.

If you have any suggestions, I am all ears. Thank you!

```
render() {
return (
  <Container style={styles.container}>

    <Header style={styles.header}>
      <Left>
      <Button transparent onPress={this.onClickHome.bind(this)}>
        <Icon active name="arrow-back" style={{color: '#000'}}/>
        </Button>
      </Left>
      <Body>
        <Title style={styles.title}>Victorise</Title>
      </Body>
      <Right>
        <Switch onValueChange={() => this.onToggleEnabled()} value={this.state.enabled} />
      </Right>
    </Header>

    --------> <DrawerNavigator /> <------ THIS IS WHERE IT IS CURRENTLY IMPLEMENTED. 

    <MapView
      ref="map"
      style={styles.map}
      showsUserLocation={this.state.showsUserLocation}
      followsUserLocation={false}
      onLongPress={this.onLongPress.bind(this)}
      onPanDrag={this.onMapPanDrag.bind(this)}
      scrollEnabled={this.state.mapScrollEnabled}
      showsMyLocationButton={false}
      showsPointsOfInterest={false}
      showsScale={false}
      showsTraffic={false}
      toolbarEnabled={false}>
      <Circle
        key={this.state.stationaryLocation.timestamp}
        radius={this.state.stationaryRadius||200}
        fillColor={STATIONARY_REGION_FILL_COLOR}
        strokeColor={STATIONARY_REGION_STROKE_COLOR}
        strokeWidth={1}
        center={{latitude: this.state.stationaryLocation.latitude, longitude: this.state.stationaryLocation.longitude}}
      />
      <Polyline
        key="polyline"
        coordinates={(!this.state.settings.hidePolyline) ? this.state.coordinates : []}
        geodesic={true}
        strokeColor='rgba(0,179,253, 0.6)'
        strokeWidth={6}
        zIndex={0}
      />
      {this.renderMarkers()}
      {this.renderStopZoneMarkers()}
      {this.renderActiveGeofences()}
      {this.renderGeofencesHit()}
      {this.renderGeofencesHitEvents()}
    </MapView>

    <View style={styles.mapMenu}>
      <Button success light={this.state.settings.hideMarkers} style={styles.mapMenuButton} onPress={() => this.onClickMapMenu('hideMarkers') }>
        <Icon name="ios-pin" />
      </Button>
      <Button success light={this.state.settings.hidePolyline} style={styles.mapMenuButton} onPress={() => this.onClickMapMenu('hidePolyline')}>
        <Icon name="ios-pulse" />
      </Button>
      <Button success light={this.state.settings.hideGeofenceHits} style={styles.mapMenuButton} onPress={() => this.onClickMapMenu('hideGeofenceHits')}>
        <Icon name="ios-radio-button-off" />
      </Button>
    </View>

    <Footer style={styles.footer}>
      <Left style={{flex:0.3}}>
        <Button info onPress={this.onClickGetCurrentPosition.bind(this)}>
          <Icon active name="md-navigate" style={styles.icon} />
        </Button>
      </Left>
      <Body style={styles.footerBody}>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.onClickTestMode.bind(this)} underlayColor="transparent">
          <Text style={styles.status}>{this.state.motionActivity.activity}:{this.state.motionActivity.confidence}% &middot; {this.state.odometer}km</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>

      </Body>
      <Right style={{flex: 0.3}}>
        <Button danger={this.state.isMoving}
          success={!this.state.isMoving}
          disabled={!this.state.enabled}
          onPress={this.onClickChangePace.bind(this)}>
          <Icon active name={(this.state.isMoving) ? 'pause' : 'play'} style={styles.icon}/>
        </Button>
      </Right>
    </Footer>

    <ActionButton
      position="right"
      hideShadow={false}
      autoInactive={false}
      active={this.state.isMainMenuOpen}
      backgroundTappable={true}
      onPress={this.onClickMainMenu.bind(this)}
      verticalOrientation="up"
      buttonColor="#7BBEC1"
      buttonTextStyle={{color: "#ffffff"}}
      spacing={15}
      offsetX={10}
      offsetY={ACTION_BUTTON_OFFSET_Y}>
      <ActionButton.Item size={40} buttonColor={COLORS.v_teal} onPress={() => this.sayIt('Hi')}>
        {!this.state.isDestroyingLocations ? (<Icon name="ios-trash" style={styles.actionButtonIcon} />) : (<Spinner color="#000" size="small" />)}
      </ActionButton.Item>
      <ActionButton.Item size={40} buttonColor={COLORS.v_teal} onPress={() => this.onSelectMainMenu('destroyLocations')}>
        {!this.state.isDestroyingLocations ? (<Icon name="ios-trash" style={styles.actionButtonIcon} />) : (<Spinner color="#000" size="small" />)}
      </ActionButton.Item>
      <ActionButton.Item size={40} buttonColor={COLORS.v_teal} onPress={() => this.onSelectMainMenu('sync')}>
        {!this.state.isSyncing ? (<Icon name="ios-cloud-upload" style={styles.actionButtonIcon} />) : (<Spinner color="#000" size="small" />)}
      </ActionButton.Item>
      {
      // <ActionButton.Item size={40} buttonColor={COLORS.v_teal} onPress={() => this.onSelectMainMenu('emailLog')}>
      //   {!this.state.isEmailingLog ? (<Icon name="ios-mail" style={styles.actionButtonIcon} />) : (<Spinner color="#000" size="small" />)}
      // </ActionButton.Item>
      }
      <ActionButton.Item size={40} buttonColor={COLORS.v_teal} onPress={() => this.onSelectMainMenu('test')}>
        {!this.state.isResettingOdometer ? (<Icon name="ios-trash" style={styles.actionButtonIcon} />) : (<Spinner color="#000" size="small" />)}
      </ActionButton.Item>
      <ActionButton.Item size={40} buttonColor={COLORS.v_teal} onPress={() => this.onSelectMainMenu('resetOdometer')}>
        {!this.state.isResettingOdometer ? (<Icon name="ios-speedometer" style={styles.actionButtonIcon} />) : (<Spinner color="#000" size="small" />)}
      </ActionButton.Item>
      <ActionButton.Item size={40} buttonColor={COLORS.v_teal} onPress={() => this.onSelectMainMenu('settings')}>
        <Icon name="ios-cog" style={styles.actionButtonIcon} />
      </ActionButton.Item>
    </ActionButton>
  </Container>
```